# Creating Ubuntu Browser App Frames

Tags: application-development

After watching the video i am inspired to create one browser but stuck at one place, could you please help me with this.

Requirement = 
- Like you displayed in your Video i wan create Multiple Buttons in my Toolbar which will open Second ToolBar or Popup Window.
- From that Pop Window i wanted to Select Specific Button Which will open My Required Browser.

Question -
- As displayed in your Video i create new BUtton and If i try to open new link using that it works but now i want to display tool bar or Popup window once any one click on that button, how can i do that.The Second Tool Bar Need to be Activated only after clicking on that button.

Things i Tried -
- As per my understanding i create Second Toolbar and on that tool bar i have created Button, now i wan know how do i link that tool bar with my Browser Toolbar button.
- I tried that by passing Signal Property in Second Toolbar in Quickly but something is missing.

- MY Code

  ```
  class TvbrowserWindow(Window):
      __gtype_name__ = "TvbrowserWindow"

      def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
          """Set up the main window"""
          super(TvbrowserWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

          self.AboutDialog = AboutTvbrowserDialog
          self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesTvbrowserDialog

          # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
          self.refreshbutton=self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
          self.SONY=self.builder.get_object("SONY")
          self.urlentry=self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
          self.scrolledwindow1=self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow1")
          self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
          self.scrolledwindow1.add(self.webview)
          self.webview.show()
      def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
          print "refresh"
      def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
          url = widget.get_text()
          print url
          self.webview.open(url)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To make a tool bar visible after clicking a button you should call the toolbar's show method after the button is clicked:

```
self.toolbar = self.builder.get_object("nameOfToolbar")
self.toolbar.show()
```

Also make sure under common settings for toolbar in glade are set "No show all" is set to yes, and "Visible" is set to no.

Comment: Thanks Sam!! I tried this but didn't worked....
self.SONY=self.builder.get_object("SONY")
self.scrolledwindow1=self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow1")
        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
        self.scrolledwindow1.add(self.webview)
        self.toolbar = self.builder.get_object("toolbar2")
        self.webview.show()
    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        print "refresh"
    def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
        url = widget.get_text()
        print url
        self.webview.open(url)
    def on_SONY_clicked(self, widget):
        self.toolbar.show()

Comment: What did it do? Did you remember to set "No show all" to yes and "Visible" to no?

Comment: Yes i did set those value. My Code going in to that button action but doesn't perform those 2 lines.